# What is the difference between following wireless card?

Tags: wireless-networking

What is the difference between following wireless card?

- Wireless-G LAN card
- Wireless-N LAN card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G is a certified standard. I think it operates at 54Mbs
N is a newer not-yet-certified standard that operates at up to 300Mbs under optimal conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Wireless-G refers to [802.11g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11g), while Wireless-N refers to [802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n).

About seven years ago, **802.11g** replaced older standards [802.11a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11a) and [11b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11b).

**802.11n** is not yet a "standard," per se, it has been around in draft form for a couple years now. And, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n), *Though not approved by the IEEE, since 2007 the Wi-Fi Alliance has been certifying interoperability of "draft N" products based on what was draft 2.0 of IEEE 802.11n specification. They have affirmed that all formerly certified products will remain compatible with the products conforming to the final standard.*

The upside of G is low-price and standard implementations. The upside of N is that it's mostly standardized and much faster than previous 802.11 variants. N is expected to be published as a "standard" in November 2009.